# How to stay at the top of form on form load?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am facing a problem with multiple forms.

When loaded, it doesn't show the tabs at the top which are part of the form and requires the user to scroll up.

I have done research. It may be related to the .SetFocus property.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
Forms!frmEnrolementForm.Tab ("tabCtl0.SetFocus")
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, user doesn't see the top part of window with tabs of tabcontrol. If so, reduce the size of tab control and whole window in order to fit in window on PC with minimal screen resolution. Also you can open desired tab page using code like

```
Forms!frmEnrolementForm.Page1.SetFocus
```

Here Page1 - is name of tabpage, not tab control. `SetFocus` is object method, not property.

Comment: After doing some testing, it is for some reason only doing this because I am using a sub form inside the tab page, if I use normal text boxes inside the tab page then it will stay on screen and just allow user to scroll down etc. But I want to be able to do this with a sub form and i have tried your method and so far no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the layout of your form, but you might be able to solve the issue by changing the "Tab Order" settings for the form.
It's under Form design tools > design > Tab Order, and you want the top/first items on your form to be at the top of the list. Ideally I'd say put all the items in a sensible order (e.g. starting with the top left and ending with the bottom right) for a good user experience, but the first item is the one that affects where the form opens.

Mine was opening in the middle of the page because my sub-form was set as the top item in the tab order, but I changed it to a button at the top of my form and now it always opens at the top.

I got this from user NeoPa in [this forum answer](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/867436-form-opens-center-we-have-scroll-up-go-top-form).